# Implement C++ template for generating an index sequence with a given range

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, c++14

So, C++14 provides struct `make_index_sequence<N>` for generating an index sequence from `0` to `N-1`. I am wondering how to implement one to generate an index sequence in a given range. For example:

```
template <size_t Min, size_t Max>
struct make_index_range;  

// make_index_range<5, 9> will give index_sequence<5, 6, 7, 8>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way you defined `index_range` (before the question was edited) the answer is simply:

```
template<std::size_t Min, std::size_t Max>
  using make_index_range = index_range<Min, Max>;
```

Which is not very useful.

So I'm going to assume you mean `make_index_range<5, 9>` will give `index_sequence<5, 6, 7, 8>`, which can be done like this:

```
#include <utility>

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t... Seq>
  constexpr std::index_sequence<N + Seq ...>
  add(std::index_sequence<Seq...>)
  { return {}; }

template<std::size_t Min, std::size_t Max>
  using make_index_range = decltype(add<Min>(make_index_sequence<Max-Min>()));
```

Or if you want `make_index_range` to be a class template, define `add` as above and then:

```
template<std::size_t Min, std::size_t Max>
  struct make_index_range {
    using type = decltype(add<Min>(make_index_sequence<Max-Min>()));
  };
```

(But with this you have to use `make_index_range<5, 9>::type` so the alias template is probably better, and closer to how `make_index_sequence` works.)

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is tagged with c++14 but it may be interesting to have a version for newer versions of the standard where metaprogramming is a little bit easier (not so obvious in this example though).

Moreover, I also needed to have a range of integers not necessarely bigger than 0, so the following code (for c++20):

```
#include <numeric>
#include <array>

template<typename T, T Min, T Max>
constexpr auto make_integer_range ()
{
    static_assert (Max>=Min);

    // we create an array filled with the integers from the given [Min,Max] bounds.
    constexpr auto arr = []
    {
        std::array<T, Max-Min+1> a;
        std::iota (a.begin(), a.end(), Min);
        return a;
    } ();

    // we create the integer sequence from the content of the array
    auto build = [&arr] <std::size_t... Is> (std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        return std::integer_sequence<T, arr[Is]...>{};
    };

    return build (std::make_index_sequence<arr.size()>{});
}

// integer sequence of -1,0,1,2,3
constexpr auto myrange = make_integer_range<int,-1,3> (); 

int main()  {}
```